# How to extract information from a txt(RIS) file in flask

Tags: python, file, flask, file-read

my file looks in a text editor like the following:

```
Firstname  - phil
Lastname  - taylor
Birthdayyear  - 1956
Country  - england
END  -
```

I stored the file in my python variable `txtFile`and when I print the file using `print(txtFile.read())` it looks like the following in the console:

```
b'Firstname  - phil\r\nLastname  - taylor\r\nBirthdayyear  - 1956\r\nCountry  - england\r\nEND  - '
```

And now I need to get the firstname, lastname, birthday year and country and store these information in variables so that I later can access the information.

So for example when I `print("His first name is " + firstName)` I'll get `His first name is phil` in the console.

The schema of the txt file is not always the same. The names like "`Firstname`","`Lastname`", "`Birthdayyear`" and "`Country`" are always the same but they are not always in the same order. So it could be that for example "`Country`" is the first line and "`Firstname`" is the last line.

I havent found a problem which is the same as mine is on stackoverflow, so maybe someone can help me out with this problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for the problem. I don't know, if this is the best way to do but it works for me:

First I went through every line of the txt file and added every line to an array. Then I
splitted every line of the array when there was a `"  - "` in the line. That splits every line for example from `["Firstname  - phil"]` to `["Firstname","phil"]` and then you can access the name if you go through every line of the array and make an if request: if the first element of the line is equal to `"Firstname"`, set your `firstName` variable equal to the second element of this line. I don't know if this is understandable, but here's how it looks like in python code... :-D

```
 txtFileToArray = []
 splittedTxtArray = []
 firstName=""

     #go through every line of the text file
     for line in txtFile:

          #put every line at the end of the array txtFileToArray and delete the "b" (binaray) at the beginning of every line
          txtFileToArray.append(line.decode('utf-8'))

    #then go through every line of the array and split every line when there is a "  - " and store the lines in a new array
     for line in txtFileToArray: 

          splittedTxtArray.append(element.split("  - "))

    #then check every line of the splitted array if there is a Firstname at the first position
    for linein splittedTxtArray:

          if(line[0] == "Firstname"):
             firstName= line[1]
```

I hope this can help you someday :-)